# building java script debugger for rhino

Tags: java, javascript, open-source, debugging, rhino

i am using tomcat server and i have added a [rhino](http://www.mozilla.org/rhino/) engine to able some scripting abilities on my users. the second phase is to provide some debug environment.

i know rhino has a debug API but i could not find any documentation/code samples about how to work with it, and build a debugger around it

any one knows?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Check this thread

[Getting Rhino debugger working in servlets](http://osdir.com/ml/mozilla.devel.jseng/2005-09/msg00077.html) which uses [Rhino debugger](http://www.mozilla.org/rhino/debugger.html).

And be sure to read the whole thread

[Rhino debugger against embedded engine](http://groups.google.com/group/mozilla.dev.tech.js-engine.rhino/browse_thread/thread/a4d26551dff6b9e8)

Some guy from the above thread managed (based on the first link I provided) to [attach a debugger to a embedded rhino instance](http://groups.google.com/group/mozilla.dev.tech.js-engine.rhino/msg/31737dd7b2361718)

Some other guy even made a little project on sourcefore (didn't test it)

[debug rhino](http://dynalang.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/dynalang/trunk/) you only need the debug and the debug-rhino folders as the rest is some other stuff

Comment: thanks :-), 
lately i have been thinking maybe i am searching information on the web in a wrong way, 

so forgive my silly question but 
how did you got to all these links??

thanks:-)

Comment: I used google. started out with "rhino tomcat debug" which yields the first link on position 4 for me. Then "rhino debugger" yields the second link on page 2 position 3b. And also reyields link 1 on page 2 position 1.

Comment: @jitter first link is broken. Is this the thread though?: http://mozilla.6506.n7.nabble.com/Re-Getting-Rhino-debugger-working-in-servlets-td164710.html

Comment: @jitter where exactly is the download for this "Rhino JavaScript debugger is a GUI" thing?: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/Rhino/Debugger

Comment: @JohnZaj https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/Rhino/Download_Rhino

Answer (score 3):

I recommend leveraging the one provided as part of JSDT, I've got embedded in a servlet environment and it took ~1 day to get going (working out how to make the rhino server match the source with the source in the eclipse workspace so they would debug properly).
http://wiki.eclipse.org/JSDT/Debug/Rhino/Embedding_Rhino_Debugger

Answer (score 1):

I wrote code in [Apache CXF](http://cxf.apache.org) to launch the Rhino debugger programatically. You might find it a useful example.