# How to do remote Javascript debugging with Rhino in intellij IDEA?

Tags: javascript, intellij-idea, remote-debugging

There is a server which uses Rhino engine to execute JavaScript files. I need to connect to that server using IDEA and debug scripts running on it. The only information I found on Rhino debugger for IDEA is on 'JS Debugger'. But what I need is some capability to connect to the server itself. So, If you can give some idea related to it, it will be really helpful.

Comment: this might help:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1653847/building-java-script-debugger-for-rhino

Comment: They mostly talk about debugging using the Rhino debugger interface and some on using Eclipse. But what I need is related to IDEA.

Comment: See if this would help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12509206/how-to-implement-an-intellij-idea-plugin-for-remote-javascript-debugging-with-rh

Comment: @ZlatinZlatev the question is from the same user :)

Comment: @Dijzeus, ye, did not notice, sorry :/

Comment: You might want to switch for WebStorm or PhpStorm for your web projects. It's still jetBrains.

Comment: Take a look at chainsaw (http://logui.sourceforge.net/) we use it with Rhino via a Jetty web server in Java, to debug our server side javascript.