# How to implement an intelliJ IDEA plugin for remote JavaScript debugging with Rhino?

Tags: javascript, remote-debugging, intellij-plugin

I need to debug scripts running on a remote server which uses an embedded rhino engine, using intelliJ IDEA. Is there any procedure that I could follow to write a plugin to support this? I need an idea as how this could be done. It will be really helpful if you can either give me some idea or point me to some resources.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IDEA has [xdebugger API](http://git.jetbrains.org/?p=idea/community.git;a=blob;f=platform/xdebugger-api/src/com/intellij/xdebugger/package.html) to support debugging. You can use [xslt debugger plugin sources](http://git.jetbrains.org/?p=idea/community.git;a=tree;f=plugins/xslt-debugger/src/org/intellij/plugins/xsltDebugger) as example.

Comment: According to what I read regarding xdebugger it is for php. Does this support javascript as well?

Comment: xdebugger API in IDEA doesn't relate to XDebug tool for PHP. This is an API in IDEA platform which allows plugins to provide debugging capabilities for their languages and frameworks. We implemented debuggers for Ruby, Python, PHP, JavaScript and other languages using this API.